# Use Studio Raster tiles in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way to use a style from the new Mapbox Studio as a raster tile source instead of vector source, using GL JS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can display raster tiles from any source in Mapbox-GL-JS, so ones from Mapbox itself certainly aren't a problem. Your source will look something like:

```
{
  type: 'raster',
  tiles: [
      'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/neil.coolmap{/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
  ]
}
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#maps) for more details.

Comment: the Felt app's documentation seems to describe this better than Mapbox's:
https://feltmaps.notion.site/Where-To-Find-Custom-Map-Backgrounds-30f85a712250421fa53a193cdf097b6a#6e52facce1f445678d20b61a1e43761a 
that says:
`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/feltmaps/clb2k8qp0002i14p8bge81ejh/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token={YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN}`

where `feltmaps` and `clb2k8qp0002i14p8bge81ejh` are your Mapbox style variables.